# Fancybox CSS not loading in production

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, sass, fancybox-2

I have the jQuery fancybox 2 plugin in use on my site. In development it's fine but in production the fancybox 2 css files are not being loaded as seen in this screenshot:

[image: Fancybox css not being loaded]

The files are in vendor/assets/stylesheets and are plain .css files

They are being referenced from my application.css.scss file as follows:

```
@import 'compass';
@import 'compass/reset';

@import '_common';

@import 'main';
@import 'pages';
@import 'coasters';
@import 'contact';
@import 'collections';
@import 'albums';

@import 'responsive';
@import 'twitterbox';
@import 'jquery.fancybox.css';
@import 'jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css';
```

Does anyone have any idea why those two css files are not being loaded. The fancybox .js files work fine, it's just the CSS ones that are not.

Neil

Comment: You should be serving one concatenated CSS file so seeing those seperate files in the network tab is wrong. Are you including the compiled CSS file SCSS has generated instead of the SCSS file?...

Comment: In my application.html.erb file I include the css like so

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>

Do you think it could be because the fancybox ones are just plain css files?

How can I get it working then?  Do I need to add .css to the precompile array or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok if you want that you css can be precompiled you can use http://css2sass.heroku.com/ for convert you fancybox.css file to scss file.

I hope this solution will helps!

Comment: Ok, If I did that then how would I add the stylesheets as I am not using the Sprockets manifest due to my use of the Compass Sass framework instead?

Comment: I would like to use that fancybox gem but it is out of date and would p[refer to use the latest fancybox version rather than an older one. I just want to get those fancybox css files working but just unsure how.

Comment: I haven't but I will give it a go. If scss IS css anyway then surely it should work. That's where I am confused.

Comment: Please check it! and post your result after precompile in your production server. Use http://css2sass.heroku.com/ for convert css to scss.